# how to return an action with odoo computed method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, action

dears i want to make records to be unique and I did it  by SQL constraints and it's worked well, and prevented me to make any duplication,

now I need to make a more advanced method, that will check the name while creating the record and search overall records so if I found it, should return an action with form view of the original record id

and here is what I had done.

```
testt = fields.Text(string="", compute='open_duplicates', required=False, )

@api.depends('name','id_num')
def open_duplicates(self):
    duplicated = self.env['muk_dms.directory'].search([('name','=', self.name)])

    if duplicated:
        print('inn')
        return {
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'muk_dms.  directory',
            'target': 'current',
            'res_id': duplicated.id,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        }
    else:
        pass
```

now if I ityped a name which already exit the method runs and print the 'inn' but it is'nt return the action

so how can I do that ??

any help will be appreciated !!

Comment: Odoo doesn't except the compute method to return anything, It will be cool if we have something like this in an onchange event but also Odoo doesn't expect that you will return an action in onchange events. So what you are trying to do is not available In Odoo, You can do for example a wizard to create a record you will ask User for the name, if the record exist return an action with that record to edit it if not return an action with no res_id to create a new record with default value for name

Comment: exactly that what I need , what is best practice to do it, to be little the same what i need

Answer (score -1):

in odoo there are 2 ways of prevention of creating duplicate record.
1). give sql constraint
2). python constraintnt

you can give one constraint at a time.

if you give SQL constraint than no need to give python constraint

If you want to raise warning when user create duplicate record you can give python constraint.

see below example

---

```
@api.constrains('name', 'state')
    def _check_name(self):
        for field in self:
            if field.state == 'manual' and not field.name.startswith('x_'):
                raise ValidationError(_("Custom fields must have a name that starts with 'x_' !"))
            try:
                models.check_pg_name(field.name)
            except ValidationError:
                msg = _("Field names can only contain characters, digits and underscores (up to 63).")
                raise ValidationError(msg)
```